# Is there a way to use a keyword as a function in Common Lisp, as one does in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, common-lisp

In Clojure one can write

```
(:foo {:foo 3 :bar 5})
```

which evaluates to 3. Is there any way to extend Common Lisp so that a keyword will act as a function that looks itself up?

Comment: You could very easily write a function that does this. What's wrong with using a function to perform this action?

Comment: Personally I really like how keywords behave in Clojure, so I was just curious if I could use them the same was in Common Lisp (my current project uses SBCL).

Comment: It looks like you can do curly-brace style hash notation in Common Lisp: http://frank.kank.net/essays/hash.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no easy, obvious or trivial ways to do that in a general way in portable Common Lisp, AFAIK.

Related functionality (for arrays) was provided in some earlier Lisp dialects, but it was not included in Common Lisp.